# Automatic .XLS to Google Sheets Converter Not Working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I have been using a script to automatically copy and convert all .xls files in a folder to Google sheets file types and deposit them in a different folder. Unfortunately, it is copying over duplicates of the same file it has already copied, even though it is specified to not do so in the script (Line 10). I am probably missing something here, but nothing has really changed, and it seems it is just spontaneously not following the IF conditional in the script. Please see below:

```
    function XLSConvert() {

    var files = DriveApp.searchFiles("title contains '.xls' and parents in 'File_ID:A' and trashed = false");
    var destinationFolderId = "File_ID:B";
    var existingFileNames = getFilesInFolder(destinationFolderId);
    while (files.hasNext()) {
        var xFile = files.next();
        var name = xFile.getName();
        try {
            if (!existingFileNames[name] && (name.indexOf('.xls') > -1)) {
                var ID = xFile.getId();
                var xBlob = xFile.getBlob();
                var newFile = {
                    title: name,
                    key: ID,
                    'parents': [{
                        "id": destinationFolderId
                    }]
                }
                file = Drive.Files.insert(newFile, xBlob, {
                    convert: true
                });
            }
          
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error with file " + name + ": " + error);
        }
    }

    function getFilesInFolder(folderId) {
        var folderId = "File_ID:B";
        var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
        var filesIterator = folder.getFiles();
        var files = {};
        while (filesIterator.hasNext()) {
            var file = filesIterator.next();
            files[file.getName()] = true;
        }
        return files;
}
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated in resolving this. Thank you :)

Comment: `existingFileNames` is a list of files not filenames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In order to retrieve the file list in the specific folder, please modify `parents in 'File_ID:A'` to `'File_ID:A' in parents` for the search query.
- In your script, when the XLSX file is converted to Google Spreadsheet, it seems that the extension is removed. This is required to be considered.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function XLSConvert() {
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles("title contains '.xls' and 'File_ID:A' in parents and trashed = false");  // Modified
  var destinationFolderId = "File_ID:B";
  var existingFileNames = getFilesInFolder(destinationFolderId);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var xFile = files.next();
    var name = xFile.getName().split(".");  // Modified
    name.pop();  // Added
    try {
      if (!existingFileNames[name]) {  // or if (!existingFileNames[name] && xFile.getMimeType() != MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS) {
        var ID = xFile.getId();
        var xBlob = xFile.getBlob();
        var newFile = {title: name,key: ID,'parents': [{"id": destinationFolderId}]};
        file = Drive.Files.insert(newFile, xBlob, {convert: true});
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error with file " + name + ": " + error);
    }
  }
  
  function getFilesInFolder(folderId) {
    var folderId = "File_ID:B";
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
    var filesIterator = folder.getFiles();
    var files = {};
    while (filesIterator.hasNext()) {
      var file = filesIterator.next();
      files[file.getName()] = true;
    }
    return files;
  }
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Search for files and folders](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files)

Comment: I'm thinking this script is removing the extension part from `name` (using `split` and `pop`), so `name.indexOf('.xls') > -1` will never be true. I'd consider modifying this condition to something like `xFile.getName().indexOf('.xls') > -1`, or store `xFile.getName()` in another variable. What do you think?

Comment: @Iamblichus Thank you for your always support. Yes. I think that you are correct. In this case, if `.xls` and `.xlsx` are used in the original filename, even when `name.indexOf('.xls') > -1` is removed, the process is the same, because of your replying. Or, in op's case, I thought that `if (!existingFileNames[name] && xFile.getMimeType() != MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS)` might be suitable. By this, the filename and mimeType can be used for checking the duplicated files. So I updated it.